# Error al ejecutar una consulta en sqlite3+crontab

Tags: python, sqlite3, crontab

Tengo un script hecho en python3 que hace scraping a una pagina web y guarda la info en una BBDD sqlite. A todo esto lo tengo montado en un VPS. El problema es cuando creo un crontab para que se ejecute el script cada cierto tiempo, cuando se ejecuta y llega a la parte de tener que escribir en la BBDD me salta el siguiente error "sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table 'nombre_de_tabla' ". Si pruebo ejecutarlo manualmente al script funciona perfectamente. Que puede ser que este fallando?

Comment: Sin un ejemplo del código es muy dificil proporcionar una respuesta, puedes leer [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad.

Comment: Probablemente el usuario (unix) que ejecuta crontab sea diferente del que usas cuando lo haces a mano. También es posible que el usuario de la base de datos sea diferente porque si no especificas ninguno use el uusario unix acivo. También, algunas bases de datos impiden la autenticación mediante contraseña si el usuario (unix) que lo intenta es `root`.

Comment: Oh, acabo de ver que la base de datos que usas es sqlite. Con esa no debería haber estos problemas de autenticación. Tal vez es que no usas una ruta absoluta hacia el nombre de fichero sqlte. Ten en cuenta que cuando ejecutas algo desde crontab debes usar rutas absolutas para todo y no esperar que PATH esté definido.

Comment: Lo solucione!. Era un problema de rutas. Gracias @abulafia